# Order of groups in R dplyr group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the `dplyr::group_by()` function in order to summarise some data. Let's assume the following dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ans = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                     sex = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 10, replace = TRUE)),
                     age = sample(c(10, 20, 30), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                     res = rnorm(10, mean = 1, sd = 10))
```

The output after the summary is as follows:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(ans, sex, age) %>% summarise(mean_ans = mean(res, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ans, sex [?]
  ans   sex      age mean_ans
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 No    Female    10    8.82 
2 No    Female    20    6.09 
3 No    Male      10    9.21 
4 No    Male      20   10.2  
5 No    Male      30  -18.9  
6 Yes   Female    10    6.94 
7 Yes   Female    20    7.20 
8 Yes   Male      10    0.838
9 Yes   Male      30    0.551
```

It seems that `group_by()` lists the groups alphabetically (conflicts resolved by the next grouping variable). What about the `age` variable - why isn't it in some order (e.g. 10, 20, 30)?

If I use `age` as the first grouping variable I get a dataframe that is sorted by all three grouping variables:

```
dplyr::group_by(age, sex, ans) %>% summarise(mean_ans = mean(res, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   age, sex [?]
    age sex    ans   mean_ans
  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>
1    10 Female No       8.82 
2    10 Female Yes      6.94 
3    10 Male   No       9.21 
4    10 Male   Yes      0.838
5    20 Female No       6.09 
6    20 Female Yes      7.20 
7    20 Male   No      10.2  
8    30 Male   No     -18.9  
9    30 Male   Yes      0.551
```

Is it always the case that `group_by()` returns a data frame ordered alphabetically by character and factor variables? According to [this discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2159) it is the case but since the discussion took place in 2016 I'd like to know whether the conclusions are still valid.

**EDIT**: I ran the original data frame with 100 rows so that all 12 groups (2*2*3) are created. It seems obvious that the data frame is sorted (including numerical columns). However, I'm not satisfied with my 'investigation' - is there a general-case proof (my simulation is one out of many). Do you know any counterexamples?

Comment: You can use arrange

Comment: what do you expect to happen with `group_by`  In the first case, the 'age' is in order within the 'ans/sex'

Comment: I've realised that `age` is after all in order. I ran the example with 100 rows in the original data frame and it is obvious that `age` in the summary data frame is sorted as well.

Comment: The github issue you linked to is referenced by [this one](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3279) from last year, which may also be useful and is more recent

Comment: note that dplyr does not sort alphabetically, it sorts by the numeric representation of the factor. Because you call `factor` without specifying the `levels` argument, it defaults to an alphabetical sorting of the factor levels. If you were to write `sex = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),levels = c("Male","Female"))` (note the addition of the `levels` argument), Male would be listed first when the df is sorted because it is the "first" level of the factor. review the `levels` argument of `factor`.